# Cordova/Phonegap can not turn off autohide on Android for splash screen

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen, cordova-2.0.0

We are using PhoneGap/Cordova 2.4. We are having trouble turning off
the auto-hide for the splash screen on the Android side. My expectation
was that that splash screen would not be hidden until there was an
explictit call to navigator.splashscreen.hide(). However for our app, the
splash screen is being hidden much sooner. This shows the user with an HTML
page that isn't ready to be interacted with.

Per the Cordova docs, we have updated our Java code to look like this

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MyApp extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 5000);
    }
}
```

In this Javascript code, we have this at end of the setup method. However, as
I mentioned, the splash screen is hidden much earlier. Also, when we take
this line out, the splash screen is still hidden. This is the code:

```
   // tons of setup code ...
    Backbone.history.start()
    Backbone.trigger('app:ready')

    navigator.splashscreen.hide()
```

We also added these 2 options to the www/config.xml. I should note that the AutoHideSplashScreen works on the iOs app but seems to have no  effect for the android app. The  other option I found from an example as I have furiously searching the internet for a solution to this problem for the past few days.

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance,

Kevin

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I'm still having this issue with PG 3.3

Comment: struggling with the same issue here. Please let us know if and how you managed to resolve it ?

Answer (score 2):

Just set a really large number for the splash screen display time.  E.g. instead of

```java
super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 5000);
```

do:

```java
super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 60000); // 60 seconds
```

It really doesn't matter what value you put here, as long as it's large enough that when your Javascript/CSS/HTML is fully loaded, the timeout hasn't occurred yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="100000" />
```

to your config.xml then later just remove it programatically as you've done when you want.

Answer (score 0):

Call must be made after deviceready

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSplashscreen) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        $cordovaSplashscreen.hide();
    })
});
```

At least this works for me. Hope it works for you guys too.